# Print string based on POST data value

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I am a beginner here so the question is maybe stupid, there is a POST data passed from a html form, and I want it to print some string based on that value, lets say

```
$_POST['veggie']
```

The data could be 1,2,3. and I want it to print "apple", "banana", "carrot". I have tried using JavaScript but it will not read POST data

```
 <script>
    whatVeggie(){
        if ($_POST['veggie'] == 1) {
            document.getElementById('myVeggie').innerHTML="apple";
        } else if ($_POST['veggie'] == 2){
            document.getElementById('myVeggie').innerHTML="banana";
        } else if $_POST['veggie'] == 3){
            document.getElementById('myVeggie').innerHTML="carrot";
          }
        }
 </script>

<body onload="whatVeggie();">
I like to eat<p id="myVeggie"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: You're mixing PHP & JS in weird way...

Comment: You're mixing Javascript and PHP? That doesn't work

Comment: Javascript is client side, POST or GET refers to server side requests. You need to get the value when its posted to the server and output it that way.

Comment: Try this? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the JS here you could use simply the PHP code :

```
<?php 
    $id='default_id';
    $veggies = ["","apple","banana","carrot"];

    if ( isset($_POST['veggie']) ){
       $id = $veggies[$_POST['veggie']];
    }
?>

<body>
     I like to eat<p id="<?php echo $id; ?>"></p>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could also use arrays to make it more compact http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-56 :)

Comment: <?php
$selVeggie = $_POST["veggie"];
$veggies = array(
    '1'  => "apple",
    '2'  => "banana",
    '3'  => "carrot",
);
echo $stores[$selStore]; 
 ?>